# Why does this function get exponentially more expensive?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-performance

If I create a function that loops through executing a bunch of dynamic queries, the process time seems to get exponentially larger. For the sake of an example, im going to use the following code. Keep in mind, I HAVE to use an execute statement in my code.

```
FOR i IN 0..10 LOOP
EXECUTE 'SELECT AVG(val) FROM some_table where x < '||i INTO count_var;
IF count_var < 1 THEN
INSERT INTO some_other_table (vals) VALUES (count_var);
END IF;
END LOOP;
```

If my for statement loops 10x, it takes 125ms to finish.
If my for statement loops 100x, it takes 4,250ms to finish.

Is there a setting I could use so that looping through it 100x would finish in 1,250ms?

EDIT: More info

```
PostgreSQL 9.2.4 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3, 64-bit
```

Each of the execute queries is doing index-only scans. Here is the plan.

```
 Aggregate  (cost=85843.94..85843.94 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=1241.941..1241.944 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Index Only Scan using some_table_index on some_table  (cost=0.00..85393.77 rows=300114 width=8) (actual time=0.046..1081.718 rows=31293 loops=1)
         Index Cond: ((x > 1) AND (y < 1))
         Heap Fetches: 0
 Total runtime: 1242.012 ms
```

EDIT2:

I rewrote the function in plperl. When I used "spi_exec_query()" on the 100x execute query, it ran in 4,250ms. When I used "spi_query()" on the 100x execute query, it ran in 1,250ms - eliminating the exponential increase.

Comment: What version of Postgre are you on?  What's your data distribution?  For example on loop one where i = 0 how many rows does your select avg(val) from some_table go after?  How many when i = 1;  Do you have an index on i?  How many rows does some_table have?

Comment: There's a bug in your code. "where < i" is not correct. You need "where SomeColumn < i". Please post the real code.

Comment: @JustBob It *really* bugs me when people post faked-up or anonymized "example" code and talk about it as if it's the real code they're having the issue with, precisely because of issues like this. (Downvoted; right now question doesn't reflect actual problem. Will remove downvote if question edited and comment made here to notify.)

Comment: Please show the information listed in http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info , like your version. I also suggest using `auto_explain` with analyze mode and explain nested enabled to get information about the timing of each loop iteration. This will produce a *lot* of log output so you'll need to post only a selection like the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 10th, 50th, 99th and 100th plans. (BTW, I'm pretty sure you're solving a problem the hard way, consider posting a separate question explaining in detail what you're trying to achieve with all this and asking if there's a better approach).

Comment: @JustBob the table has 12m rows. The example is an abstracted version of my more complicated function, but the example i've shown is the root source of the exponential increase in time. There is an index on the table and the query is an index only scan. I have 22GB of ram and have set all the shared_buffers, effective_cache_size settings per Gregory Smith's High Performance book.

Comment: @CraigRinger I should have posted the query plan and version, etc. My apologies. As far as explaining in detail what im trying to do, it gets really complicated, but i've narrowed down the exponential increase in time to that loop. I guessing that once the loop runs past a certain amount of loops, im running out of memory somewhere or something gets written to disk? I haven't read much about function performance though.

Comment: @NickBoutelier You haven't confirmed whether it's the `SELECT` or the following `INSERT` that's becoming more expensive with each iteration, though. I suspect it's the `EXECUTE 'SELECT ...'` but you need to confirm that. `auto_explain` will be the best way to do so.

Comment: It's definitely the EXECUTE. I've run the function without the INSERT and the timing is still high.

Answer (score 1):

#### Why the slowdown?

Calculating an average for row that qualify for `x < 100` is obviously *much more* expensive than calculating the same for `x < 1`. How much, we do not know, there is *nothing* in your question.

Without knowing the data distribution in your table, we can only guess. There could be 5 rows for `x = 5`, and 5M rows for `x = 77`. Test:

```
FOR i IN 90..100 LOOP ...
```

vs.

```
FOR i IN 0..10 LOOP ...
```

And consider the numbers from

```
SELECT x, count(*) FROM some_table WHERE x < 100 GROUP BY 1;
```

Also, comparing two data points is hardly grounds for claiming "exponential growth". In a comment you speculate that Postgres might be starting to write to disk, which might just explain it.

#### Plain SQL alternative

Either way, there is nothing in your question to support your claim:

> I HAVE to use an execute statement

*Do you really?* This plain SQL statement does exactly the same as your PL/pgSQL fragment, but might be quite a bit faster:

```
INSERT INTO some_other_table (vals)
SELECT avg_val_by_x
FROM  (
    SELECT avg(val) OVER (ORDER BY x) AS avg_val_by_x
    FROM   some_table
    WHERE  x < 10
    ) sub
WHERE  avg_val_by_x < 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

First I want to echo Craig's request for real information.  In my experience, loops become exponentially slower based on very nitty gritty details.  I don't know if this will answer the question but I will give an example I ran across in my own work.   If nothing else it will give a good example of something to look for when troubleshooting this issue.

In an earlier incarnation of the bulk payment functions in LedgerSMB, we'd loop through the invoices (which would come in as a 2d array).  We would then insert two rows for each invoice, and then update a third.  For 10 invoices this would be fast.  For 100 there would be a noticeable slowdown, and for 1000 (yes, this could happen, 1000 invoices paid at once to a vendor), the system would take a long time (as in hours).

The problem had to do with caching.  The system would effectively begin missing caches and these would increase in frequency until every write was effectively, a new bit of random disk I/O.  Consequently the system would slow down as the loop got big.

Our solution was to write all rows to a temporary table and then run two insert queries based on the contents of the temporary table and finally one update based on the same.  This cut the time from hours down to something like a minute or two.

If your case is at all like what you are saying, PostgreSQL will more effectively cache the first rows than the last rows.  Moreover you are going to end up with the following:

where i is 1, the answer is a1, where i is 2, the answer is (a1 + a2)/2, where i is 3, it is (a1 + a2 + a3)/3, and so forth.  So you have both caching issues and computation issues.

A third possibility, raised in your plperl edit is that you may be getting a plan for a few rows re-used for a plan with many more rows, to the point where the plan no longer makes sense.  Note index only scans are not necessarily cheaper if a large part of the table is to be accessed since you lose the OS readahead caching.

Without seeing real code though it is impossible to see what the real problem is.  The above are shots in the dark or things to check.